# How to custom Retrofit with AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, retrofit

I use Retrofit. Sometime I want integrate with AsyncTask for some purpose like Dialog Loading...

Here is my way:

```
public class RetrofitAsyncTask<T extends ResponseModel> {
public interface OnCompleteListener<T extends ResponseModel> {
    public void onComplete(T t);
    public void onError(Exception e);
}

public interface JsonConverter<T extends ResponseModel> {
    public T getModel();
}

protected OnCompleteListener<T> onCompleteListener = null;
protected JsonConverter<T> jsonConverter;
protected ProgressDialog progressDialog;
protected int requestCode = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

public static RetrofitAsyncTask newInstance() {
    return new RetrofitAsyncTask();
}

public RetrofitAsyncTask setOnCompleteListener(OnCompleteListener<T> l) {
    onCompleteListener = l;
    return this;
}

public RetrofitAsyncTask setJsonConverter(JsonConverter<T> converter) {
    jsonConverter = converter;
    return this;
}


public RetrofitAsyncTask setProgressDialog(ProgressDialog dlg) {
    progressDialog = dlg;
    return this;
}

public RetrofitAsyncTask setRequestCode(int reqCode) {
    requestCode = reqCode;
    return this;
}

public void execute() {
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Exception>() {
        private T result;

        @Override
        protected ProgressDialog getDialogRunOnPreStart() {
            /** Retrun dialog will display. Will process on onPre & onPost. But current I will ignore it.**/
            return progressDialog;
        }

        @Override
        protected Exception doInBackground(Void... params) {
            if (jsonConverter == null) {
                return null;
            }
            try {
                result = jsonConverter.getModel();
                result.setRequestCode(requestCode);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return e;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Exception e) {
            if (onCompleteListener != null) {
                if (e != null || result == null) {
                    onCompleteListener.onError(e);
                } else {
                    onCompleteListener.onComplete(result);
                }
            }
        }
    }.execute();
}

}
```

In this case class ResponseModel is Empty class.

```
public class ResponseModel {/** You will custom some filed default here **/}
```

Next you will define some Service Api.... look like:

```
public interface MyService {
@GET("/path")
public User getUserInfo(....);
}
```

(Notes class User Must be extend from ResponseModel).
Then you will custom some RetrofitAdapter...

Finally to use RetrofitAsyncTask you will do something like:

```
RetrofitAsyncTask.newInstance()
                .setJsonConverter(
                        new RetrofitAsyncTask.JsonConverter<User>() {
                            @Override
                            public User getModel() {
                                return MyService.getUser(...);
                            }
                        }
                )
                .setOnCompleteListener(this)
                .setRequestCode(requestCode)
                .execute();
```

That's way I done. But current I feel it not good.
(setJsonConverter get much line :|, If you have any idea to make it better & shorter please comment ! Thanks so so much !)

Comment: You've to post your code in your question post not in the answer...

Comment: I make it as question :)